# Splitting a string by using two substrings in Python

Tags: python, string, search

I am searching a string by using `re`, which works quite right for almost all cases except when there is a newline character(\n)

For instance if string is defined as:

```
testStr = "    Test to see\n\nThis one print\n "
```

Then searching like this `re.search('Test(.*)print', testStr)` does not return anything.

What is the problem here? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The re module has re.DOTALL to indicate "." should also match newlines.  Normally "." matches anything except a newline.

```
re.search('Test(.*)print', testStr, re.DOTALL)
```

Alternatively:

```
re.search('Test((?:.|\n)*)print', testStr)
# (?:…) is a non-matching group to apply *
```

Example:

```
>>> testStr = "    Test to see\n\nThis one print\n "
>>> m = re.search('Test(.*)print', testStr, re.DOTALL)
>>> print m
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1706300>
>>> m.group(1)
' to see\n\nThis one '
```

Comment: I suppose not, although if it serves as a reminder to always try your code at the console first even if it costs you a few minutes, it has its value..

Comment: DSM: If it has value, why did you delete it? :P